# Shrinking UICollectionViewCell on touch - delaysContentTouches issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, touch

I have a scrollView, which contains modules with collectionView and modules with tableView. So you can scroll up and down with scrollView, and scroll right and left in collectionView modules. After pressing on collectionView cell, user is navigated to another view controller.

[here is an approximate sketch of how the UI looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqyPq.png)

I need to make cells in collectionView shrink on touch. The problem is, that when I try to do this - I have a slight delay between touch and the start of shrinking. I am using this code to make the cell shrink:

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didHighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
            cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.95, y: 0.95)
        }
    }
}
```

I have learned that the delay happens because `delaysContentTouches` property is automatically set to `true` in UICollectionViews, in order to detect properly scrolling and selecting touches of user. So I have set it to `false`, and also since collectionView was located inside the scrollView as I mentioned above - I had to also set `delaysContentTouches` to false in the scrollView in order to remove the delay between touch and shrinking for collectionView cells.

The problem is that when I set `delaysContentTouches` to false in scrollView - it also automatically applies to tableView, and cells inside tableView also begin highlighting immediately when you're just scrolling up and down, which is definitely undesired behaviour in this case.

I have tried setting `delaysContentTouches` in tableView to `true`, but this did not help to prevent this behaviour.

Is there any way to make my cells shrinking immediately only for collectionView, without touching the functionality of tableView highlighting in this case? I am quite new to this so would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the storyboard?

Comment: The logic is divided into several storyboards, but I have made a sketch of how the UI looks like and attached the link above (you can see it after tapping on "here is how the UI looks like")

Comment: Why do you have a scrollview and both a tableview and a collectionview within it? Can you send a screenshot of the output? I believe there is a better way to set up that screen.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps or not, but why aren't you using UICollectionView's `didSelectItemAt` instead of `didHighlightItemAt`?

That may be another reason for the delay.

Comment: thank you for your reply! the problem is that didHighlightItemAt is called before didSelectItemAt, so user is able to see the shrunk cell before the navigation to another view controller after pressing on cell;
if I put the animation in didSelectItemAt, then I will need to put navigation in the completion block of animation, which creates a slight delay between pressing on cell and transition to another view controller, because the transition starts only after animation finishes;
if I do not put the transition in completion block, then you just cannot see the shrunk cell before transition

Comment: sorry I didn't understand you were actually trying to do something else other than shrinking it. Anyway I'm now understanding better your problem but unfortunately I don't really know how to solve it at the moment.